# RStudio can't enter certain key combos as modified shortcuts

Tags: rstudio

In RStudio's `Tools > Modify Keyboard Shortcuts`, I want to modify the following actions to have the indicated keyboard shortcuts:

`Open Next Tab`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd>
`Open Prev Tab`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>

but the screen that captures keyboard input won't let me input <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd>. I can do other keyboard shortcut combinations - just not those two. I cleared the default shortcuts for the following actions:

`Go to Next Section`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> (cleared)
`Go to Prev Section`: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> (cleared)

Then I tried again to reassign `Open Next Tab` to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> but again it didn't let me put in this key combo. But I could put in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for example.

Why are <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> locked out of use? I was able to use them like this a year ago. The default behavior of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageDown</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp</kbd> moving to the most recently used tab, instead of sequential order (like Chrome, Office, everything else), is not preferred.

Comment: RStudio has a community Discourse server where the community provides support for the RStudio free tier.

Comment: What version are you using? I'm having save problem with `RStudio 1.1.463 - Ubuntu 16.04+/Debian 9+ (64-bit)` and can echo OP's experience that this keyboard shortcut edit has worked in the past.

Comment: If you are on Linux, perhaps it's related to the issue described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/104813/thunar-keyboard-shortcut-to-change-tab/108914#108914

Comment: Strangely this has resolved itself for me. I noticed it began working at some point after I'd assigned Ctrl+Alt+PageDown/PageUp to these actions. I restored keyboard shortcuts to see if I could reproduce the initial problem, but the shortcuts still worked as desired.

Comment: @Adam Smith I ended up using the latest R Studio preview release (for Linux) and the issue appears to have been corrected.